# Why is there no Swap command?

Tags: programming-languages, language-features

In many programming languages, I see programmers always struggle to swap 2 variabeles. Most of the time it costs 3 copies and a temporary variabele to accomplish it.

Why do programming language dont have build-in support for something basic like this?

Comment: Please be more specific about which languages you're taking about. Many languages do include it in their standard library.

Comment: Probably because outside of writing sorting algorithms for the standard library, you rarely have to swap elements.

Comment: @JohnK I mean in C or C# or whatever common language

Comment: C++ has `std::swap` but it has no commands (but functions and statements and expressions)

Comment: @Muis Could you specify which programming languages you're referring to and what you mean by "built-in support"? As others have pointed out, many scripting languages support multi-value assignment, and others have a swap function in their standard library.

Comment: Also, at the machine code level, it usually does not cost what you believe it costs.

Comment: `I see programmers always struggle to swap 2 variabeles` - IMO this is a much more serious problem than the lack of a swap command. If swapping two variables is so common for the program you're trying to implement, why not make your own swap utility function or macro

Comment: Some processors include atomic register swap instructions for just this purpose.  If a compiler's optimizer recognizes a `temp=x; x=y; y=temp` pattern, it may well use it.

Answer (score 15):

*Because you usually don't need it*

Swapping the contents of two variables is a task that is mostly used at university or programming classes.

It's real-life use is limited to sorting algorithms and (maybe?) encryption. If you are writing a algorithm like this, you are probably capable of swapping two values anyway.

That being said, most programming languages don't have many things *built in* to begin with. A lot of the functions we use every day are part of some library or runtime environment. These functions are often added in an incremental way, but only if they solve issues users of the particular language or library had: It's all about demand.

Answer (score 4):

In some languages, variables cannot be assigned (more than once, at their definition). In particular in functional languages like Ocaml (or Haskell) variables cannot be swapped (this would be meaningless).
In these languages mutable references or mutable fields are not the same as variables. And functional languages don't have commands or statements, but only expressions!

Answer (score 2):

There are other methods for doing the same thing.  Some of which are more flexible, allowing rotation.

In Python:

```
x = 1
y = 2
z = 3
(x, y) = (y, x)
print x, y
(x, y, z) = (z, x, y)
print x, y, z
```

Other languages allow similar behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like [InterlockedExchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or like [STL's swap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap), though neither are language specific STL is close enough.